# Block all connections except a single host server ? (block by server not by app)

Tags: networking, internet, data-connection, data-plan

My mobile company offers a free package for facebook with unlimited bandwidth , however when I open my 3G connection the mobile automatically connects to unknown servers (maybe google) and the mobile company charges me for that connection.

The question in simple words:
How can I make all connections blocked (even google) except facebook.com?

Comment: Funny, I allow all *except* facebook.com

Answer (score 1):

If you're rooted, you can configure `Firewall` rules to block all except Facebook, but I don't think your problem is that complex:

> when I open my 3G connection the mobile automatically connects to unknown servers.

Unable to understand what that mean as I can't OPEN my 3G connection. Seems to me, either you are talking about opening web browser or `Background Data` is screwing you. In the first case, make your homepage Facebook. In the second case, turn off `Background Data` from `Settings` ~> `Accounts and Sync`. Done!

---

If you want to do it with Firewall way, open [Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm). Switch to root by `su` command (your device must be rooted for that). Now, execute following commands in sequence:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d facebook.com -j ALLOW`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d * -j DROP`

(Do it on your own risk after proper backups. Some devices become unstable after it.)